# How can I reference the backbone view from a kendo ui treeview event handler?

Tags: backbone.js, kendo-ui, treeview, marionette

I'm using the Kendo UI treeview with Backbone.js along with Marionette.js The treeview is inside a view component and works well execpt for one area.  To start, I initialize  the treeview when I call the view render method

```
View.myPanel = Marionette.ItemView.extend(
    render: function () {
            this.treeview = this.$el.find("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: this.hierarchicalDataSource,
                  dataTextField: ["item"],
                  dragAndDrop: true,
                  loadOnDemand: false,
                 drop: this.onDrop
            }).data("kendoTreeView"),
             this.treeview.expand(".k-item");
    },  

      onDrop: function (e) {
            ...
            code to create model goes here ......
           ... 
            this.saveItem(localModel, false);
   }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I try and call *this.saveItem*, I have no reference to *"this"*. . Normally *"this"* would be the view itself.

Instead *"this"* refers to the treeview object. I see the event object inside the drop handler but no reference to the view.

I tried to extend the treeview with BackBone.Events but that causes me to lose the drag and drop functionality. I also tried passing the view object as a parameter to  the drop handler but that replaces the event parameter in the onDrop function.

Comment: did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's `bind` and `bindAll` methods may hep you.

```
View.myPanel = Marionette.ItemView.extend(
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,'onDrop');
    },
    render: function () {
            this.treeview = this.$el.find("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: this.hierarchicalDataSource,
                  dataTextField: ["item"],
                  dragAndDrop: true,
                  loadOnDemand: false,
                 drop: this.onDrop
            }).data("kendoTreeView"),
             this.treeview.expand(".k-item");
    },  

      onDrop: function (e) {
            ...
            code to create model goes here ......
           ... 
            this.saveItem(localModel, false);
   }
}
```

To know more see [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

Here is sample EXAMPLE posted it there on underscore site

```
var buttonView = {
  label  : 'underscore',
  onClick: function(){ alert('clicked: ' + this.label); },
  onHover: function(){ console.log('hovering: ' + this.label); }
};
_.bindAll(buttonView, 'onClick', 'onHover');
// When the button is clicked, this.label will have the correct value.
jQuery('#underscore_button').bind('click', buttonView.onClick);
```

Here `this` in callback function `buttonView.onClick` points correctly to `buttonView`and not to the bound DOM element (which is usual).

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about backbone or marionette, but it seems like you can use the `ItemView` variable you created:

```
View.myPanel.saveItem(localModel, false);
```

**Update**

Have you tried a self-executing function that passes the `View` object in as a local variable and returns the `ItemView` object:

```
View.myPanel = (function(view) {
    return Marionette.ItemView.extend(
        render: function () {
            this.treeview = this.$el.find("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: this.hierarchicalDataSource,
                dataTextField: ["item"],
                dragAndDrop: true,
                loadOnDemand: false,
                drop: this.onDrop
            }).data("kendoTreeView"),
            this.treeview.expand(".k-item");
        },  

        onDrop: function (e) {
            ...
            code to create model goes here ......
            ... 
            view.myPanel.saveItem(localModel, false);
        }
    );
})(View);
```

Comment: View is not available inside the onDrop function

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI explicitly sets the context for event handlers to the widget that triggers the event; use a closure to keep access to your view:

```
render: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.treeview = this.$el.find("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: this.hierarchicalDataSource,
        dataTextField: ["item"],
        dragAndDrop: true,
        loadOnDemand: false,
        drop: function (e) {
            that.onDrop(e)
        }
    }).data("kendoTreeView"),
    this.treeview.expand(".k-item");
}
```